# Creating rolling text effect in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-activity

So, I'm extremely new to Android Studio, and I was assigned a simple game project, sort of like a choose your own adventure. I was trying to do a rolling text effect like how text goes onscreen in most RPGs (like Undertale). Does anyone know if this is possible using just Java & XML, and if so, then how I would go about doing it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579952/get-the-acceleration-without-gravity.You may can try the above link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Java, but I would try something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < Text.Length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(Text.Substring(0, i));
}
```

Where Text is your message.
Hope this helps!